# Can't see addressfield on custom form

Tags: forms

I created a module that displays a very simple form: name of organization, address and contact info. I've been able to add all components to the form with the exception of the address. I installed the latest addressfield module, which supposedly adds the ability to use a form item of type addressfield but it doesn't show up. I'm sure I am missing something. All I did was add the following code to my form:

```
$form['application']['address'] = array(
    '#type' => 'addressfield',
    '#title' => t('Address'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => array('country' => 'US'),
    '#description' => "Please enter your address.",
  );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think addressfield provides a Form API element. You'd have to create one.

Comment: I think you can...https://drupal.org/node/970048

Comment: That's an issue in the queue, which provides a patch. You'll have to patch the development version of the module with latest patch.